# Windows: can a process's main thread switch between NUMA nodes while running?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, numa

I'm writing a c++ library that will be read as a DLL by another (3rd party) application.

I would like to set the affinity of the threads in my library's threadpool to the same NUMA node as the application's main thread. That way all threads operate within the same NUMA node and I get the most efficient memory access/allocations across all threads.

My current process is as follows: get the NUMA node the main thread is running on, find all cores within that node, then set my threadpool threads' affinity to those cores.

The main question is whether or not the application's main thread can switch between NUMA nodes at will...there's no point in me matching my threads' NUMA affinity to the main thread's NUMA node, if the main thread can change which node it's on a moment later.

Would the application as a whole have to have its NUMA affinity restrained in order to ensure no node-jumping occurs? Or are threads guaranteed to stick with whatever NUMA node they're initially spawned on? I know the OS scheduler can cause threads can jump between cores, but I can't find any info about whether threads can jump between NUMA nodes...